# How to add to cart or wishlist without Logged in

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-5

I want to add  a product to my cart But for that i want to logged in the user.Means after he logged in only he can see his cart. But after logged in if he sees the cart, he should see the the product just he added to cart but he saw the old one.Though I put the url on session in controller.How do i make it correct?

**Here is show Login form :**

```
     public function showLoginForm()
        {
            Session::put('url.intended',\URL::previous());
            return view('cart.login');
        }
```

**Add to Cart controller :**

```
public function addCart(Request $request)
    {
        if(Auth::check())
        {
        $name = $request->name; 
        $product = Product::where('name' , '=', $name)->first();
        $product_id = $product->id;
        $product = DB::table('carts')           
                ->where('carts.product_id','=',$product_id)
                ->where('carts.status','=',1)
                ->select('carts.product_id')
                ->first();

        if(!$product){
            $cart = new Cart(); 
            $checkBox = Input::get('additionals');
            if (is_array($checkBox)){
            $cart->additionals = array_sum($checkBox);
        }
        else {
            $cart->additionals =0;
        }
            $cart->user_id =Auth::user()->id;
            $name = $request->name; 
            $product = Product::where('name' , '=', $name)->first();
            $cart->product_id = $product->id;
//          $product = Product::find($cart->product_id);
            $cart->price =$product->price;  
            $cart->status = 1;  
            $cart->save();
            return redirect('shop-cart');           
        }
        else {          
            return redirect('shop-cart');
            }
        }

        else{
            return redirect('/login');
        }
    }
```

**And Login controller :**

```
protected function login(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required',
        ]);

        if (auth()->attempt(array('email' => $request->input('email'),
             'password' => $request->input('password'))))
        {
            if(auth()->user()->is_activated == '0'){
                 Auth::logout();
                return back()->with('warning',"First please active your account.");
            }

            else{
                return Redirect::to(Session::get('url.intended'));

            }


        }
        else{
            return back()->with('error','your username and password are wrong.');
        }
    }
```

**Add to Cart Route:**

```
 Route::get('add-to-cart/{name}','CartController@addCart');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public function addcart(Request $request)
{   
    $id=$request->id; $time=60*24*14; /*60 * 24 * 14 = 14 drays 60=minutes 24=hours 14=days*/
    $value=0;
    if( Cookie::get('cart')!==null ){
        $anonim=Cookie::get('cart');
        DB::table("cart")->insert(["anonim"=>$anonim,"product_id"=>$id]);
        return 0;
    }else{
        $value=DB::table("cart")->max("anonim")+1;
        if(empty($value)){
            $value=0;
        }
        DB::table("cart")->insert(["anonim"=>$value,"product_id"=>$id]);
        $cookie = cookie('cart', $value, $time);
        return response()->cookie($cookie);
    }

}
```